# jquery ui datepicked, change cell colour of disabled day

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, uidatepicker

I have a jquery ui datepicker, I am using the beforeShowDay to disable some dates and assign a custom css.

i.e.

```
.css-class-to-highlight {

background: none #000000;
border: 1px solid #000000;

}
```

This only adds a faint border around the date cell, I would also like to change the  transparency and fill colour, how would I achieve this?

I am using this css theme
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

Answer (score 0):

Add this code, this will take care of everything.

```
 var selectedDate = new Date(date);
 var msecsInADay = 86400000;
 var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);

 jQuery('#yourCntrlId').datepicker("option", "minDate", endDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

i managed to get to a solution I was comfortable with the following css;

```
.ui-datepicker-unselectable.css-class-to-highlight span.ui-state-default {

background: none #000000;
border: 1px solid #000000;

}
```

the only thing I wasn't able to resolve was removing the transparency.